# How to redirect with querystring in django urlpatterns?

Tags: django, django-views, query-string, django-urls

I'm looking for a way to make a redirect from one url to another with query string parameter.
Is it possible to get a redirect from `/orders/` to `/orders-new/?queryParam=1`
How should I change `RedirectView` in a first line?

```
url(r'^orders/$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='orders-new'),
    name='orders'),
url(r'^orders-new/$', orders_list_new, name='orders-new'),
```

Comment: Now what happens when you visit `/orders/` ?

Comment: @MohitSolanki I get redirect to `orders-new` view without query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing, For a quick solution Write a simple view for `/orders/` url and in it's dispatch method redirect url to `/orders-new/` with any string parameters
You can redirect as below

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return redirect(reverse('<app_name>:orders')
```

Comment: And have to combine this solution with @neverwalkaloner answer to add query string param to url

Comment: Yeah, it looks dirty but internally ReditectView Work Like the same way I suggest you.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) argument like this:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

url(r'^orders/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='{}?queryParam=1'.format(reverse_lazy('orders-new'))),
    name='orders'),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I got the following error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'project.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.`

Comment: @DaniilMashkin try to move line with `orders` url under `orders-new` line.

Comment: @DaniilMashkin can you show content of `project.urls` file?

Comment: project/urls.py https://gist.github.com/danmash/e02abc2cb95fe0d5e7f590d71c76efe7

orders/urls.py (app urls) https://gist.github.com/danmash/b871faefd27550e13b58c53beb982714